# How to use cache() correct?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.1.0 and I try to load a graph into GraphX.
A fraction of my code looks like the following:

```scala
val distinct = context.union(r1, r2).distinct;
distinct.cache()

val zipped = distinct.zipWithUniqueId
zipped.cache
distinct.unpersist(false)
```

When I'm executing it on the cluster the first stage that is executed is:

```scala
distinct at Test.scala:72
```

But after this operation has finished I can't see an entry in the "Storage" tab of the Spark UI. The next stage is:

```scala
zipWithUniqueId at Test.scala:78
```

But rigth after that it also starts this again:

```scala
distinct at Test.scala:72
```

Shouldn't this result be cached?
Is it useful to cache a RDD if it is used only once?

### Edit:

I forgot to mention that I also get a **Fetch failure** at `zipWithUniqueId at Test.scala:78`

#### Possible solution for the Fetch-problem

Possible solutions are described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3633) which could be a bug in Spark version 1.1.0.

Also possible solutions from Andrew Ash from the spark-user mailing list:

> There currently seem to be 3 things causing FetchFailures in 1.1:
>
> 1) long GCs on an executor (longer than spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout default 60sec)
>
> 2) too many files open (hit kernel limits on ulimit -n)
>
> 3) some undetermined issue being tracked on that ticket
>
> [Source](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201409.mbox/%3CCA+-p3AH5AamGTkE6ViyCWb24oHSNmAqm1Q9x53aBWB_aRvwBOw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cache` will be applied the first time that the RDD is evaluated. This means that, to be effective, `cache` should precede some action that produces an RDD that you will use more than once. 
Given that `cache` is applied on RDD evaluation, if you have a linear RDD lineage that is only executed once, cache will only occupy memory without delivering any advantage.

So, if your pipeline is:

```
val distinct = context.union(r1, r2).distinct;
val zipped = distinct.zipWithUniqueId
zipped.cache
```

Using `cache` between `distinct` and `zipped` will not be of any use, unless you need to access `distinct` data again down the road. Giving that you're `unpersisting` it immediately after, makes me think otherwise.

In a nutshell, only use `.cache` if the evaluated RDD will be used more than once. (eg. iterative algo, lookup, ...)

Cache spark-shell example:

```
val rdd = sc.makeRDD( 1 to 1000)
val cached = rdd.cache // at this point, nothing in the console
```

[image: SparkUI persistence tab: no persisted RDDs]

```
cached.count // at this point, you can see cached in the console
res0: Long = 1000
```

[image: SparkUI persistence tab: cached RDD is available]

```
val zipped = cached.zipWithUniqueId
val zipcache = zipped.cache // again nothing new on the UI
val zipcache.first // first is an action and will trigger RDD evaluation
```

[image: SparkUI showing the 2nd cached rdd]

```
cached.unpersist(blocking=true) // force immediate unpersist
```

[image: SparkUI not showing unpersisted RDD anymore]